# many to many relationship in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, relationship

I have created 2 models in rails and modified the models classes to add a many to many relationship (with `has_and_belongs_to_many`)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

When I create a User though the web interface, I am not asked to select some categories.

Did I miss somthing ? I read that another table was required but it semmed it was in the case of `has_many` and not `has_and_belongs_to_many` statement).

Could you please help ?

I think this is a newby question but...

Thanks a lot,

Regards,

Luc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For HABTM you need a join table called categories_users.  Use this migration:

```
def self.up
  create_table :categories_users, :id => false  do |t|
    t.integer :category_id
    t.integer :user_id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your view look like? Rails's scaffolding won't account for many-to-many, so you will need to handle it yourself.

What does your data store look like? If you are using a RDBMS, then for many to many relations you typically need a junction table. Many-to-many is not naturally handled by most (all?) SQL databases.

Comment: Ok, I know better understand why this table is needed. I just though it was created automatically by rails. Thanks a lot.